# How to disable sending cookies for a certain route only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been searching for this information and haven't found anything.

I want to disable cookies only for a particular route. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you cannot prevent the browser from sending you cookies

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran I can

Comment: I didn't know.. how did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work in the routes file, but you can always use this in associated controllers:

```
before_action :skip_cookies
```

and as a private method:

```
def skip_cookies
  request.session_options[:skip] = true
end
```

That should avoid including any cookies for the actions inside the controller